# Cannot launch appengine SDK, even after re-install

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine

Today when I attempted to launch the appengine SDK (python) I saw the error "Errors occurred" - see image below. More details:

1. The log file referenced in the error message does not exist at that location
2. I tried uninstalling the SDK entirely, and re-installing 1.9.13.msi (python)
3. It's on Windows 7, 74 Pro, python 2.7
4. I tried renaming the app files at %APPDATA%/local/temp/appengine.*
5. I'd been using app engine fine for weeks on this machine. Yesterday my machine failed to go to sleep properly, as it often does. At power up it booted into a new/clean Windows - ie. it crashed and lost all its state. (Warning dont buy a Thinkpad T440s for Windows until they have this fixed..). I *suspect* that something was corrupted when the machine crashed.
6. I tried restarting Windows, of course ;)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can also try the Cloud SDK, which runs fine for me and which makes updates easier. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: Just tired the Cloud SDK. Same error, similar error message - only difference is that it specifies a slightly different path. Log file still doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/Uphb04hV2tg/K6vL4osY_xgJ

I renamed the file 'google_appengine_launcher.ini' at users/[my profile]/Goolge